# Connection reset by peer in postgres

Tags: postgresql, backup

<pgAdmin 4 - DB:postgres>]>:idleLOG: **could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer**

Trying to take backup and getting error after 100 or 200 GB backup .Idle backup size is 400 GB and I'm taking backup on same server.I'm using posttgres 12. I'm taking backup of 700GB database.

Comment: What is the corresponding error from db server's log file?

Comment: '11419127', $3 = '1', $4 = '/home/Sap_attachments/2022/10Nov2022/DOM-1801-10Nov2022-093613102/marraigeProofCertificate.jpeg', $5 = '689338', $6 = '28854365'
<2022-11-10 09:36:17.768 IST [22849<127.0.0.1><pg_dump><sayali><jkbo_sl_db>]>:idle in transactionLOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
<2022-11-10 09:36:17.770 IST [22849<127.0.0.1><pg_dump><sayali><jkbo_sl_db>]>:idle in transactionLOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction

Comment: Since both sides say the other side hung up, then it sounds like a firewall or gateway is sabotaging you.

Comment: Firewall is inactive still getting error